# How to extract the coefficients from a long exponential expression?

Tags: functions, algebraic-manipulation

I have the given function:

```
   FD[t_]= 210.381 + (17.3242 + 4.85667 I) E^(-I t) + (17.3242 - 4.85667 I) E^(
      I t) + (3.17784 - 3.49448 I) E^(-2 I t) + (3.17784 + 3.49448 I) E^(
      2 I t) + (8.87257 - 0.0140159 I) E^(-3 I t) + (8.87257 + 
        0.0140159 I) E^(
      3 I t) - (1.08113 + 2.92438 I) E^(-4 I t) - (1.08113 - 
        2.92438 I) E^(
      4 I t) + (9.1099 + 7.17952 I) E^(-5 I t) + (9.1099 - 7.17952 I) E^(
      5 I t) + (1.82308 - 9.69558 I) E^(-6 I t) + (1.82308 + 
        9.69558 I) E^(
      6 I t) + (4.60651 + 2.81956 I) E^(-7 I t) + (4.60651 - 
        2.81956 I) E^(
      7 I t) + (8.08371 + 6.23971 I) E^(-8 I t) + (8.08371 - 
        6.23971 I) E^(
      8 I t) + (7.04355 + 19.6089 I) E^(-9 I t) + (7.04355 - 
        19.6089 I) E^(
      9 I t) + (7.65561 + 13.8731 I) E^(-10 I t) + (7.65561 - 
        13.8731 I) E^(
      10 I t) + (20.3217 + 8.677 I) E^(-11 I t) + (20.3217 - 8.677 I) E^(
      11 I t) - (4.34572 - 17.6074 I) E^(-12 I t) - (4.34572 + 
        17.6074 I) E^(
      12 I t) + (4.45996 + 19.7283 I) E^(-13 I t) + (4.45996 - 
        19.7283 I) E^(
      13 I t) + (1.86735 + 19.0595 I) E^(-14 I t) + (1.86735 - 
        19.0595 I) E^(
      14 I t) - (7.75273 - 11.0137 I) E^(-15 I t) - (7.75273 + 
        11.0137 I) E^(15 I t)
```

and I tried to extract the coefficients with method 1:

```
Coefficient[FD[t], t, 10]
```

method 2:

```
forms = {[FD[t]]}
```

method 3:

Using

```
TreeForm[FD[t]]
```

I get:

[image]

But neither of these method works.

How can I get those coefficients as a set of points?

Thanks

Comment: Coefficient works on polynomials. You do not have a Polynomial there.

Comment: Thanks Nasser!  .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Cases[expr, a_ Exp[b_ t] :> {b, a}]

(* {{-I, 17.3242 + 4.85667 I}, {I, 17.3242 - 4.85667 I}, 
    {-2 I, 3.17784 - 3.49448 I}, {2 I, 3.17784 + 3.49448 I}, ... } *)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great.

Comment: I find you code does not work in this case: sol = DSolve[{y'''[x] + y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y'''[0] == 1, y''[0] == 1,
     y'[0] == 0}, y[x], x];
d3U[x_] = D[sol, {x, 3}];
d2U[x_] = D[sol, {x, 2}];
dU[x_] = D[sol, {x, 1}];
TrigToExp[sol]
Cases[sol, a_ Exp[b_ t] :> {b, a}]

any reason why it does not?

Comment: @Vangsnes, first, you have $x$ instead of $t$. Second, you have a more nested expression, so you have to tell ``Cases`` to look deeper. Use ``Cases[sol, a_ Exp[b_ x] :> {b, a}, All]``

Comment: Interesting! Thanks a lot for this!